# Kivy & Cython Installation

Tags: python, osx-mavericks, cython, kivy

(1) I began to install Kivy for Python from the link here: [Kivy Mac Download](http://kivy.org/#download) , then I noticed that I didn't have Cython...

(2) So I downloaded Cython after referencing this thread: [ChrisB's Kivy-Cython Resolution](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/kivy-users/OHlwNvOuA6Y/oRDSPyduL2YJ), however I didn't quite understand his **2** solution, so I...

(3) Attempted to install Cython via:

```
python setup.py install
```

...while in the correct directory of course.

Which yielded:

```
The following error occurred while trying to add or remove files in the installation directory:

[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/test-easy-install-948.write-test'
```

(4) And now I'm trying to get around this error to complete my Cython installation to complete the Kivy installation.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed via `sudo python setup.py install` DOH!